# Question on meaning of notation

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces

What does the following mean in context to Differential Geometry?  The book I am reading uses it without explanation.

$${\left. {Df\,} \right|_u}(V)$$

Comment: The obvious question, what book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notations will vary from book to book, but if I had to guess I would read that as "The derivative of $f$ at the point $u$ applied to the vector $V$".

For an example consider the function $f$ on the real line given by $f(x)=x^2$. Then $Df \mid_x (h) = 2xh$.